# Automapper EF class to model class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, automapper

I have a model class like this:

```
public class mOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Models.mOrderPay> OrderPays { get; set; } = new List<mOrderPay>();
}

public class mOrderPay
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

and EF table structure like this:

```
table | Order
-------------------
PK    | int   | Id
-------------------
.....

table | OrderPay
-------------------
PK    | int   | Id
FK    | int   | OrderId  - to Order.Id
      | int   | Amount
```

I want to convert EF class to model class via Automapper, how can I do it?

Comment: If you want to convert EF classes, then show the EF classes, not db tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
cfg.CreateMap<Dal.Order, Models.mOrder>()
.ForMember(s => s.OrderPays, c => c.MapFrom(m => m.OrderPays));
```